# Cake php validation rule 'isUnique' gives error on edit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The cake php validation 'isUnique' gives error on edit

```
 var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
        ),
       'isUnique' => array (

           'rule' => 'isUnique',

           'message' => 'This person name already exists.'
       )

)
);
```

Here when add a new person with existing name gives an error `This person name already exists`  that is fine.
But on edit of already existing person also gives the  same `isUnique` error.

How I can sort it out ?

Comment: Could you post your edit logic?

Comment: Is it possible to update with `name` that is not in records, if it is already in records(except current name on update), show an error message on update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
'isUnique' => array (

           'rule' => 'isUnique',

           'message' => 'This person name already exists.',

           'on' => 'create',
 )
```

From the book:

> If a rule has defined ‘on’ => ‘create’, the rule will only be enforced
>   during the creation of a new record. Likewise, if it is defined as
>   ‘on’ => ‘update’, it will only be enforced during the updating of a
>   record.

If, however, they are allowed to change the name, and you still need uniqueness from other records, you may need a custom unique validation which would check that if it is identical to the record of the id I'm editing allow that, otherwise fail.

Edit:
**Do NOT use the following - cakes built-in isUnique validation handles it already**

Note - untested code (its late, I will test in the morning) but it will give you the idea

Add the following to the model and change  'rule' => 'isUnique', to  'rule' => 'isUniqueName' and remove 'on' => 'create'

```
public function isUniqueName($fields) {
        $conditions = array($this->alias . '.name' => $this->data[$this->alias]['name']);
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
            $conditions[$this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey . ' <>'] = $this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey];
        }
        return $this->find('count', compact('conditions')) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to update with `name` that is not in records, if it is already in records(except current name), show an error message on update.

Comment: I would highly recommend not doing it this way. the validation rules should work even with edit views as long as you pass the ID along (cake knows that this record has to be exluced from the isUnique validation check).

Comment: Thanks @mark Thats what I thought but I was thrown off because what the way the first comment to my answer was phrased. To confirm it, http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#l-3004 so Jusnit just use my first answer